# Как изменить масштаб Гугл карты?

Tags: html, css, google-maps-api, google-maps

На сайте есть табы с картами,все карты в html вставлены через , все карты отображаются, но одна с очень большим масштабом.
[image]

сайт https://redcat.ua/places/ раздел магазины

Спасибо

Comment: У инстанса карты, есть метод `setZoom(number)`, который принимает число. Используйте его

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На странице находится 3 карты , две из которых скрыты и имеют display: none; из-за этого и появлялась проблема с масштабом карты.